# CSS grid/flexbox spacing issues at small pixel sizes

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to create a 3x3 grid of dots using CSS grid or flexbox. *At larger sizes I have no trouble evenly spacing the grid, but at smaller sizes (4px by 4px dots w/ 2px gaps) the spacing is off.*

Here's a link to [a CodePen](https://codepen.io/pmillspaugh/pen/ExZyQdb) reproducing the problem, and I've pasted a Stack code snippet below. This is what the code produces now:

[image: PNG snip of code result – flexbox (top) & grid (bottom)]

I've tried many other fixes and looked through others' questions to no avail. E.g. using other CSS flexbox properties like `justify-content: space-between`, nesting divs to create 3 distinct rows, using margin and padding instead of grid/flex gaps, and using absolute positioning to center the dots. Examining the dots in DevTools, each rendered dot seems to be offset slightly from its respective div, and the spacing differences are not uniform.

Thank you in advance for any help on this!

```css
/* CSS */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#flexbox, #grid {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.dot {
  background: gray;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2px;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="flexbox">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>

<div id="grid">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the image of how it looks on the small screen?

Comment: I edited the question to include a PNG snip. Thank you, @ManasKhandelwal

Comment: Kind of hard to tell but does this change to your grid rule make a difference? `#grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 4px); grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 4px);  grid-gap: 2px; }`

Comment: Appreciate the response, @BertW. Unfortunately that did not fix it

Comment: I tried using a different monitor, and the spacing issues went away. So the issue seems to only happen on my main screen (even if the browser window is exactly the same dimensions on my separate monitor). I also tried using different browsers – same result. Perhaps it's a bug on my screen, although I worry others will also see the misalignment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok – got to the bottom of it: my laptop screen resolution was set to 125% (recommended by Windows), which caused the misalignment. It went away when I set the resolution to 100%. Hope this helps anyone running into similar issues. Thanks again Manas and Bert for the responses.